# wait-for-it Command not found when run inside a .sh file

Tags: bash, sh

Say I'm executing a file named `run.sh`. I have this commands inside this file:

```
SERVER=${SERVER:-"localhost:5555"}
wait-for-it ${SERVER}
```

When I `echo` the `${SERVER}`, I can see that it is correctly set to `newserver:5555`. When I run `run.sh` file, I get this error:

```
Command 'newserver:5555' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: "[wait-for-it](https://pypi.org/project/wait-for-it/) is a script that will wait on the availability of one or more TCP services (i.e. host:port) before executing a user-defined command."

Comment: Why do you think there is a command named `wait-for-it`? Where is it installed, and is that directory on your `PATH`?

Comment: it is installed because when I go 'pip freeze', I can see it.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the directory is on your search path.

Comment: How can I ensure that?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you don't have a space between `SERVER=` and `${SERVER:-"localhost:5555"}` that you removed when copied the example here? The error seems to be on the first line. Add `set -x`.

Comment: What does `wait-for-it` do ?  It seems that it is trying to execute its argument as a command, and the command `newserver:5555` is not found.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I updated my question to explain what wait-for-it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wait-for-it website](https://pypi.org/project/wait-for-it/) that you linked:

```
Usage: wait-for-it [OPTIONS] [COMMANDS]...

  Wait for service(s) to be available before executing a command.

Options:
  -h, --help               Show this message and exit.
  -v, --version            Show the version and exit.
  -q, --quiet              Do not output any status messages
  -p, --parallel           Test services in parallel rather than in serial
  -t, --timeout seconds    Timeout in seconds, 0 for no timeout  [default: 15]
  -s, --service host:port  Services to test, in one of the formats: ':port',
                           'hostname:port', 'v4addr:port', '[v6addr]:port' or
                           'https://...'
```

So you probably want:

```
SERVER=${SERVER:-"localhost:5555"}
wait-for-it --service ${SERVER}
```